# Keyboard not working after suspend on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, suspend, 22.04, lg

I've got a new LG gram laptop (LG Electronics 17Z90Q-K.ADC9U1), running Ubuntu 22.04, fully encrypted disk using ZFS. Everything is working except when the computer wakes from suspend, the keyboard no longer works. I've included the output from `libinput list-devices`. I'm guessing the AT translation may be some kind of buffer translation from a UART device between the keyboard and cpu, but just a guess. My guess is this device is put to sleep, but not woken on power-up. I have to shutdown and power-up every time I store my laptop, so any help is appreciated. I've tried everything I can search online, but to no avail. Thanks

```
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard
```

Edit: I have since tested the USB ports, and can confirm USB keyboards work on wake. From what I can see in the dmesg, it's an issue with the i8042 IC. I've tried editing all combinations of kernel grub options to no avail.

Edit 2: I figured out the fix. Turns out it was a thermal sensor that was the issue. Run `sudo rmmod int3403_thermal` to see if it stops the dmesg spam. If it does, insert `acpi_mask_gpe=0x6E` into /etc/default/grub.

Comment: As usual, update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: You could check if an external USB keyboard is affected on the same way or not... If not, it also would give control back to you, so you could investigate more after a resume.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Correct me if I'm wrong but the only updates are for a couple windows drivers and lg software. [link](https://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers) Or were you referring to something else?

Comment: @redseven - Very clever. I'll test that asap.

Comment: @redseven - I can confirm the USB ports work on wake up. I've narrowed it down to a linux kernel issue that sends a sleep signal to the Intel i8042 IC, but is unable to wake it up. Tried multiple fixes, including adding grub entries to no avail, Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have enough info now to open a bug report for Ubuntu. But in my experience is not much better than asking a question here. ;)

Comment: I have this problem also with Gigabyte Aurus laptop. Resume after suspend about 80% of the time the keyboard doesn't work. My workaround is to then suspend and wake again and it usually then works on the second go. I've also found that after doing many suspend/wake cycles the whole system becomes unresponsive and I have to power cycle.

Comment: I figured out the fix. Turns out it was a thermal sensor that was the issue. Run `sudo rmmod int3403_thermal` to see if it stops the dmesg spam. If it does, insert `acpi_mask_gpe=0x6E` into /etc/default/grub. @calabash